# Android how to catch search key

Tags: android, search, key, onkeydown

In older releases I was able to catch the search key

`(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH)`

when I was using the onKeyDown method. But now with new release of android it is not working anymore.Is there another possibility to catch the search key?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to override [Activity.onSearchRequested()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSearchRequested%28%29) instead?

Comment: The 'onSearchRequested()' method is the important part that triggers the search UI.

Comment: The 'onSearchRequested()' method is the important part that triggers the search UI. But that is not what i want. I need to catch the search key in order to inhibit the google search function. In other words i like to use the search key for my internal app purpose.

Comment: Yes, just override onSearchRequested() and then don't call the base class if you handle it. You can disable search entirely by just providing an empty onSearchRequested() method.

Comment: onSearchRequested() is not helping because neither onKeyDown() or onSearchRequested() gets invoked when the HW search button is pressed (onKeyDown() got invoked in older Android versions).